# Android Studio logcat not showing stack trace for assertionerror or error

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, stack-trace

I used to get full stack trace of my error to help debug on Android Studio (v1.0.2) when using my Phone . However, after I upgraded to 5.0 from 4.4 on my Android phone, I have stopped seeing the full stack trace (which are still being reported on ACRA) in Android Studio logcat

```
03-17 16:01:43.581  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1426608103590
03-17 16:01:43.581  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
03-17 16:01:43.581  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1426608100515
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Server: nginx/1.6.2
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ Vary: Accept, Cookie
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
03-17 16:01:43.591  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ {"image": "userprofile/user_pic_test50@xyz.com/profile_pic_52.png", "cover_image": "", "status": "success", "first_name": "Test", "last_name": "User"}
03-17 16:01:43.601  10674-15920/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (150-byte body)
03-17 16:01:43.751  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-17 16:01:43.771  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a AssertionError exception for com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug. Building report.
03-17 16:01:43.781  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/ACRA﹕ Using default Report Fields
03-17 16:01:44.431  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/Settings﹕ Setting font_size has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
03-17 16:01:44.961  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/Settings﹕ Setting wifi_saved_state has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
03-17 16:01:45.071  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/ACRA﹕ READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
03-17 16:01:45.141  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/ACRA﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
03-17 16:01:45.251  10674-10674/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/ACRA﹕ Writing crash report file 1426608105000.stacktrace.
```

Is this something to do with OS upgrade (and I need to do something in the Developer Options on my phone) or is it Android Studio specific?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to enable developers options once again....just try it once..

Comment: Developer options is enabled. I disabled and enabled it once again and put a int a = 5/0 to fake a runtime error. The stack shows up completely on Android Emulator (using 5.0 nexus 5), but still does not show up when I use my android Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Same with my N5 and GNex. Have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Same problem here. Android Studio debugging seems to have destabilized over the past few weeks to months, (See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172523 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=119564)